# Call method from one webform to another webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I try to call method from one webform to another webform like this

report.aspx

```
public  void BindReport(data crystalReport, DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string region)
        {
      T1 t = new T1();
List<griddataresult_Result> dsc = t.griddataresult(fromdate, todate, 
region).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("OwnerName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));
         foreach (var c in dsc)
            {

dt.Rows.Add(c.ID, c.OwnerName, c.RegNo, c.total_voilatio);
            }

            crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["region"].Text = "'" + region + "'";
            crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["fromdate"].Text = "'" + fromdate + "'";
            crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["todate"].Text = "'" + todate + "'";

            crystalReport.SetDataSource(dt);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
        }
```

and in webform .aspx

```
protected void Report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reports b = new Reports();
            data crystalReport = new data();
            b.BindReport(crystalReport,Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate.Value),   
            Convert.ToDateTime(todate.Value), regiondrop.SelectedValue);
        }
```

when i try this show error like this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

on this line

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't and it smells like a bad design. 
A page is instantiated when requested and goes trough a lifecicle that doesn't happen when you instantiate it manually.
You have two choices: move the desired method to an external class or create a base class `PageBase : Page` that includes the relevant method and use it as parent when needed.

```
public class ReportPageBase:Page
    {
        protected void RenderReport(string param1, string param2)
        {
            //Your implementation
        }
    }

    public class Report1 : ReportPageBase
    {
        protected void Button_Click(EventArgs args)
        {
            base.RenderReport("str1", "str2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: bad design? i mean when i click on button report should open on another webform  isn't this right?

Comment: If the method is needed in many pages, create a base class for report pages and include there the relevant code.

Comment: @user6628729 I have updated my answer with a code sample

Comment: check this paste .. here i paste complete code http://pastebin.com/GsGfZ3cm

Comment: and i try your code but this show error Error 5 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'BindReport' 
Error 3 { expected
Error 2 Invalid token ':' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error 4 Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration